# Detecting Collision and move to start location of object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having an issue where the movement continues in the same direction after hitting the wall, this continues in an endless loop. What do I need to do to move the player back to its location when it hit the wall? Any thoughts?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

  Vector3 pos;                                // For movement
  public float speed = 7.0f;                         // Speed of movement
  public float movementRange = 2.0f;
  public Transform relativeTransform;
  private Vector3 lastPos;
  IEnumerator RotateMe(Vector3 byAngles, float inTime)
  {
    var fromAngle = transform.rotation;
    var toAngle = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles + byAngles);
    for (var t = 0f; t < 1; t += Time.deltaTime / inTime)
    {
      transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(fromAngle, toAngle, t);
      yield return null;
    }
  }

 

  void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
  
  {
    if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Wall"))
    {
      
       this.transform.position = lastPos;
       
    }  
  }


void Awake()
{
    Application.targetFrameRate = 30;
    
    
}
  void Start()
  {
    pos = transform.position;          // Take the initial position
  }



  void FixedUpdate()
  {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) && transform.position == pos)
    {        // Left
      
      pos += -relativeTransform.right * (movementRange);
      
      
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) && transform.position == pos)
    {        // Right
      pos += relativeTransform.right * (movementRange);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && transform.position == pos)
    {        // Up
      pos += relativeTransform.forward * (movementRange);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) && transform.position == pos)
    {        // Down
      pos += -relativeTransform.forward * (movementRange);

    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q) && transform.position == pos)
    {
      StartCoroutine(RotateMe(Vector3.up * -90, 0.8f));
    } //Rotate Left

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && transform.position == pos)
    {
      StartCoroutine(RotateMe(Vector3.up * 90, 0.8f));
    } //Rotate Right

    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, pos, Time.deltaTime * speed);    // Move there
  }

}
```

This is for an old school dungeon crawler and want to make the movement back to the original location when the player hit the key to move into the wall.

Answer (score 0):

You should

- also reset the `pos`
- stop possible rotation animations

So e.g. like

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{       
    if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Wall"))
    {
        StopAllCoroutines ();
      
        transform.position = lastPos;
        pos = lastPos;       
    }  
}
```

In general though if this object is using a `Rigidbody` you shouldn't use `Transform` at all but rather go through the `Rigidbody` component like

```
rigidbody.MoveRotation(Quaternion.Slerp(fromAngle, toAngle, t));
yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
```

and

```
StopAllCoroutines();
      
rigidbody.position = lastPos;
rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
pos = lastPos;
```

and

```
rigidbody.MovePosition(Vector3.MoveTowards(rigidbody.position, pos, Time.deltaTime * speed);
```

And do **not** calculate with Euler angles! Rather directly use `Quaternions`

```
var fromAngle = transform.rotation;
var toAngle = fromAngle * Quaternion.Euler(byAngles);
```

I would also make sure there are never any concurrent routines:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q) && transform.position == pos)
{
    StopAllCoroutines ();
    StartCoroutine(RotateMe(Vector3.up * -90, 0.8f));
}
// Use else to handle buttons exclusively
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && transform.position == pos)
{
    StopAllCoroutines();
    StartCoroutine(RotateMe(Vector3.up * 90, 0.8f));
}
```

Comment: I worked through the script and ran into the issue of when I hit an object tagged with "wall" I get bounced back. Is there a way to stop this? Making the gameobject have 9999 drag?

Comment: No .. rather reset the `rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;` ;)